# how remove effect of collapse from li

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap collapse but I got a problem when click on a "a href" inside the collapse, If I click any href inside the ul collapse ul collapse back, how can I resolve this problem?

```
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" >

       <li>
       <a href="#collapse1" id="btn-1"   data-toggle="collapse" 
        aria-expanded="false"><b>A</b></a>
        <ul  class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked  collapse" id="collapse1"           role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-1" >        
       <li class="submenu"><a  href="~/a/a-1">a-1</a></li>
       <li><a  href="~/a/a-2">a-2</a></li>              
       </ul>
   </li>


    <li>
    <a href="#collapse2"  data-toggle="collapse"><b>B</b></a>
        <ul id="collapse2" class="collapse nav nav-pills nav-stacked  text-center" aria-expanded="false">
        <li ><a  href="~/b/b-1">b-1</a></li>
        <li ><a  href="~/b/b-2">b-2</a></li>
        <li ><a  href="~/b/b-3">b-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like clicking an `a` is redirecting you to another page.  You'll have to open the collapse on the page load based on which page you have loaded.  If it's not redirecting, then you'll need to include more code.